# Symfony 3.4 application hitting a memory leak when doing a cache:clear with warmup

Tags: php, symfony, memory-leaks, symfony-3.4, php-7.2

I am upgrading my application from Symfony 2.8 to 3.4 and I am taking advantage of the new autowiring feature.

As part of my Services refactoring for autowiring I have went from this in 2.8:

```
appbundle.services.course_manager:
    class:  AppBundle\Services\CourseManager
    calls:
        - [setDoctrine, ['@doctrine']]
```

to no definition in 3.4 and simply using the `@required` annotation like this:

```
class CourseManager
{
   use DoctrineTrait;
}

trait DoctrineTrait
{  
    /**
     * @required
     * @param RegistryInterface $doctrine
     */
    public function setDoctrine(RegistryInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }
}
```

When I run `bin/console cache:clear --env=dev -vvv` I get the following:

```
// Warming up cache...                                                                                                 

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1021054976 bytes) in /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Resource/ReflectionClassResource.php on line 137

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1021054976 bytes) in /private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Resource/ReflectionClassResource.php on line 137
Fluent\Logger\FluentLogger Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1021054976 bytes) signup.php: {"message":"Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1021054976 bytes)","context":{"exception":{}},"level":500,"level_name":"CRITICAL","channel":"php","datetime":{"date":"2018-10-17 08:18:41.313528","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"extra":[]}
08:18:41 CRITICAL  [php] Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1021054976 bytes)
[
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException {
    #message: "Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1021054976 bytes)"
    #code: 0
    #file: "/private/var/www/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Resource/ReflectionClassResource.php"
    #line: 137
    #severity: E_ERROR
  }
]

In ReflectionClassResource.php line 137:

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException]                                       
  Error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1021054976 bytes)  

Exception trace:

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

However, when I run it with `--no-warmup` I do not hit the memory leak, presumably because it's not booting up the application.

The output doesn't indicate where the error originates from so I am having difficulty in tracking it down.

Also, I am keen to retain my traits for DI as it is throughout my application and would require substantial refactoring to remove them and replace it with a constructor just for DI.

Comment: I'd guess that you've created some kind of loop with the autowiring and your traits. But i think that we're not really able to help you without knowledge of your project.

Comment: @KhorneHoly Is there any profiling tool I can use to track it down?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know any. Maybe you could track the issue down if you look into the /cache directory and try to analyze what was created what is missing, but I can't give you any guidance here.